# How to use window.open() in current window and keep same window name

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I tried window.open('url','_top') to open new window in current window.but window name lost.
also tried window.open('url',window.name),but new window mode(IE11) not override parent window mode(IE8).

I hope your can help good scheme is put forward !

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.open ('YourNewPage.htm','_self',false)
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp